# Get Value more then one TextField From Tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have Table and First 2 Row in Textfield. I Want to get Value from Both But i how Can I get that

[Image Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTARk.png)

Code :-

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("csttblcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle[indexPath.row]
    txtcontent = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as! UITextField
```

Comment: This is just `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Where do you want to get value? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I need to get value from textfield on  button Action

Comment: Do you use a static table?

Comment: yes I want to get data from textfield which are in tableview and store data in database so as both different textfield data need to store in different variable

Comment: Thanks guys my issue solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("csttblcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddSubTableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle[indexPath.row]
cell.Textfieldcell.tag = 10 + indexPath.row
cell.lbladd.tag = 20 + indexPath.row
}
@IBAction func btnAddData(sender: UIButton)
{
txtFname = tble_subsc.viewWithTag(10) as! UITextField
txtfdis = tble_subsc.viewWithTag(11)  as! UITextField
let fname = txtFname.text
let dis = txtfdis.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
guard let cell1 = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)) else { return }
guard let textField1 = cell1.viewWithTag(101) as? UITextField else { return }
print(textField1.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your IBAction:

```
let button = sender as! UIButton   // Button that called the IBAction

var labelText = ""

if let cell = button.superview!.superview {   // Cell that the button is in
    currentCell = cell as! UITableViewCell
    if let label = currentCell.textLabel {   // Get the label in that cell
        labelText = label.text   // Assign the string to our variable, declared above
    }
}
```